# Run-Time Error Checks Doubt

Tags: visual-c++

My application is divided into several modules(dlls). The threads in the application will go through different modules (dlls).  If I change a run time error check (for Eg: /RTCs) in one work space (module), should I change this in all work spaces of the dlls that the application uses?

Thanks!

Comment: @ognian VS 2008/2010 solution

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation all of them seem to only have local effects, so there is no reason they would have to be matched in all the projects. However as they will only reveal problems in those modules where they are enabled, you probably want to set them in all modules in debug configuration (they are incompatible with optimizations).

Note, that the easiest way to set the same options for all projects is to use the "property sheets" feature. It's hard to discover—you have to open the "Property Manager" window from "View" menu to find it.